# Unable to uninstall 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2' because something depends on it

Tags: json.net, myob

I am using sample code from [some sample code from MYOB](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/accountright_sample_csharp) to access their [SDK](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/AccountRight_Live_API_.Net_SDK)

After updating to the latest SDK, when I try to build I get an error

```
Unable to uninstall 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2' because 'MYOB.AccountRight.API.SDK.2016.2.99' depends on it.
```

The error occurs on using JsonConvert

How can I work around this?

[Update]

I was able to install 11.0.1 Newtonsoft.Json and then to upgrade it.

Why did I need to resort to this?